# Spring Boot Lombok API not serializing

Tags: spring-boot, lombok

I have a simple Spring Boot controller with a simple Object, which is annotated with Lombok, when I tried to post data to the controller the object to not serializing.

```java
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@ToString(callSuper = true)
public class Employee extends BaseDomain {

    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String mobileNo;

    @PostMapping
    public Employee saveEmployee(Employee employee) {
        log.debug("Employee save {}", employee);
        return employeeService.saveOrUpdateEmployee(employee);
    }
}
```

Comment: First, you need to split in different layers your logic, you can't have an entity and its controller at the same time if you know some principles of layers infrastructure, so create a custom controller and remove all logic related to `requests/response` on the entity, I mean creating a `EmployeeController` and moving `saveEmploye` that is the main issue which will solve it.

Comment: That was someone edited inside after I posted. post method is inside Employee Controller

Answer (score 0):

```
 @PostMapping
    public Employee saveEmployee(@Requestbody Employee employee) {
        log.debug("Employee save {}", employee);
        return employeeService.saveOrUpdateEmployee(employee);
    }
```

@Requestbody is missing